# Batch script to edit another batch script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to append to a specific line within another batch script. How can I do this? Is this trivial in .bat or would I be better of using Python. I know much more Python than I do .bat.

I have a line in the .bat that sets path.

it looks like `set path=%TEST_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;`

I need to find this line and tack on another environment variable to the end. I can do in Python but would rather do .bat.

So what I'm looking for would be this

```
set path=%TEST_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;%ADDTHISVAR%
```

Comment: To output `%ADDTHISVAR%` literally by a batch file, double the `%`-signs like `echo/%%ADDTHISVAR%%`; for the overall task, use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to walk through the lines of the other batch file; in the loop body, you could do an [`if` comparison](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html), or you could use [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to search for the specific line you want to modify...

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is read each line of the file and simultaneously write them out to a new temp file (or hold it in memory). Check that each line is not `set path=%TEST_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;` and if it is, then append your var to it before you write it out to your temp file. And then replace or overwrite your existing file with the temp one.

However, the next time you try to run the script and search for that line, it will already have the `%ADDTHISVAR%` so you'd need to check if it's not already there.

You may be better off just setting an environment variable before running your `.bat` file and having that use the env variable in place of `%ADDTHISVAR%`